# Regarding creation of Galois field

Tags: matlab, galois-field

When I do this:

```
>> data_source = randsrc(1,493, 0:1);
>> msg=gf(data_source,9); %creation of Galois field
```

in Workspace it creates a variable as: `msg=<1x493 gf>`.

and when I open it in variable-editor, it is showing `gf object: 1-by-65` as first entry in (1,1) position.

What is the origin of this `1-by-65`? What does it mean ?

Comment: I don't think the variable editor works for class `gf`.  :/  `msg(1)` looks fine on the command line.